# Addition of a few features to Directory listing

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I'm a newbie to web development. I'm using the directory listing tool provided by http://www.directorylister.com/. However, I managed to make a few tweaks here and there, however, I'm stuck here.

[image: Screenshot:]

I need to create the following 3 buttons that do the following:

Create directory: This will create a directory(I get an option to name it before creation) in the current path I'm in. Current path/directory is mentioned at top left.

Upload file: This will give me the option to upload files current directory I'm in.

Sync: This will basically just run a bash script I have made.

I managed to create buttons using Create Directory , however, I was facing issues making it work right.

Any kind of help would be really helpful.

Regards,

Rohan Dsouza

Comment: This sounds like homework and we're not here to do your homework for you. You at least need to take a stab at writing the code then asking for help if you get stuck.

Comment: _" however, I was facing issues making it work right."_ What are the specific issues that you are facing? Do you call `bash` script from `php`?

Comment: For eg,

<form action='' method='post'>
<button type='submit' name='mkdir'>Create directory</button>
<button type='submit' name='Upload'>Upload</button>
<button type='submit' name='Sync'><a href="?run=true">Sync</a></button>

<?php if ($_GET['run']) {   # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
exec("/opt/scripts/master_sync.sh");
}
?>

Does not run the bash script I have made. The permissions on the bash script are not an issue.